# How to split column based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, hana

I want to split a column using HANA Database view SQL as seen below:

Essentially, a column has a value of 1000, 100 or 100 in a string after 4 values

For example:

```
ABCD1000XYZ
ABCD100XYZ
ABCD10XYZ
```

I need to split the column into

```
ABCD 1000 XYZ
ABCD 100 XYZ
ABCD 10 XYZ
```

[image]

Comment: It depends on what database you are using. Please tag the question with the correct DBMS

Comment: You need to use a regular expression function for this but it is not clear what to match against. It looks like you have 4 groups in the column judging by your image but how is each group defined?

Comment: So Im tying to split the "text name" column into 4 separate columns the first column has 4 characters ex. G21A or C36A and the like for all the records. 

The second one is what I am having trouble with splitting it by 1000, 100, 10 as seen in column 2. column 3 is whatever is after the 1000 or 100 or 10 and before the "P" or "D". The column 4 is D and everything after it.

Comment: *before the "D"* isn't there a case that a D exists in the 3d part?

Comment: Nope, basically anything after the "1000", "100" or "10" you can say its the customer number and the "DXXXXX" is the material number. Example: 962446530 is a customer number and PLTBR55 is another example of customer number. "DXXXXX" all are the material numbers.

Comment: The last row has both a P and a D?

Comment: yeah the P... is the Customer number and D... is the Material. Which still follows the principle after the 10 anything after and before the D is the Customer number and DXX.. is the Material. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression to use for identifying the different groups looks like

```
(^.{4})(1[0]{1,})([A-Z0-9 ]*)(D.*$)
```

where each group is within ()

To extract each group in a select you need to use this reg expression 4 times (or 3, see below) and select one group per time (column)

```
SUBSTRING_REGEXPR('(^.{4})(1[0]{1,})([A-Z0-9 ]*)(D.*$)' IN text_name GROUP 1)
```

So the Sql query would be

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_REGEXPR('(^.{4})(1[0]{1,})([A-Z0-9 ]*)(D.*$)' IN text_name GROUP 1) AS Col1,
       SUBSTRING_REGEXPR('(^.{4})(1[0]{1,})([A-Z0-9 ]*)(D.*$)' IN text_name GROUP 2) AS Col2,
       SUBSTRING_REGEXPR('(^.{4})(1[0]{1,})([A-Z0-9 ]*)(D.*$)' IN text_name GROUP 3) AS Col3, 
       SUBSTRING_REGEXPR('(^.{4})(1[0]{1,})([A-Z0-9 ]*)(D.*$)' IN text_name GROUP 4) AS Col4
FROM some_table
```

Since the first column is always the 4 for characters it could be extracted with a normal SUBSTRING call

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(text, 1, 4) AS Col1, ...
```

I hope this helps, I don't have access to SAP Hana so the Sql is untested although the regular expression has been tested.
*Edit, I noted that you have a space in the fourth row so I added it to the reg expression.*